# How is this expression well-defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

I am going through the book "Introduction to Tensor Product of Banach Spaces" by Raymond Ryan. The tensor product of vector spaces is introduced in the first chapter which I briefly outline now.

Let $X,Y$ be vector spaces and for each pair $(x,y)\in X\times Y$, define a functional on the space of bilinear forms on $X\times Y$ by $$(x\otimes y)(A)=A(x,y),$$ where $A$ is a bilinear form on $X\times Y$. We then define the tensor product $X\otimes Y$ to be the subspace spanned by these elements. Thus a typical tensor in $X\otimes Y$ looks like $u=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ix_i\otimes y_i$; however this representation of $u$ is not unique. The action of $u$ on a bilinear form $A$ is then given by $$u(A)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iA(x_i,y_i).$$

Question: After this the author writes - "Of course, the value of this expression is independent of the particular representation chosen for $u$." I don't get how this is so obvious. Is it inherent in the definition, or do I need to prove that $u(A)$ is well-defined? How should I convince myself that this is indeed so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by definition -- according to this definition, what a tensor *is* is neither more nor less than the totality of what it does to the $A$s. If two linear combinations of $(x\otimes y)$s *don't* define the same value for every $A$, then by virtue of that fact they must be representations of *different tensors*.

That does make the sentence you're quoting slightly mysterious -- it makes it look like there is more going on than there is. I suspect the author may have confused himself slightly by thinking about a *different* (but equivalent) common definition of $X\otimes Y$ where $X\otimes Y$ is the space of all *formal* linear combinations of $(x\otimes y)$s, with a certain subspace quotiented out. By that definition it is actually something that needs to be proved that when you apply a bilinear form to a tensor the result doesn't depend on which representation of the tensor you're using.

Comment: I somewhat understand your explanation, and I suspect there is indeed some confusion introduced by the author.